# ExecutorService: how to check if my Callable is being executed?

Tags: java, future, executorservice

I'm using an `ExecutorService` to process task requests from multiple threads and use the `Future` returned from the `ExecutorService#submit()` to track the progress of the tasks.

I want to remove the request and give a feedback to the requesters if after some timeout their request has not yet been processed at all.

So I want to know if the task request is currently being processed, if it is then I'll wait for it to finish or otherwise I'll cancel it and give feedback to the requester.

Any helps and tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too late for an answer but why don't you define your tasks to have some kind of volatile "isStarted" flag ? Then you can query the flag in your catch clause.

Comment: Hi NitinS, thanks for the answer. Indeed in the end I put a volatile flag to indicate whether is has started or not. I was trying to avoid that and only use the ExecutorService's related functionalities but it got too complex :/

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Future.cancel(false)` it will allow the task to run to completion if it has already been started.  Even if you use `cancel(true)` it may do so anyway, unless the talk performs an operation which is interruptable or you check the interrupted flag.

I suspect you don't need to know if the task has started or not.  Even if you had this method, it is possible that the task has not started when you check, but has started by the time you try to cancel it.

Comment: Too bad for me that I actually need to know if the task has been started or not, so I can tell the requester that it has reached the timeout without being processed at all :(

Comment: I tried to use the `boolean` return from `Future.cancel(false)` but it always return true even if the task is ongoing. When this happens in the end I'll give two feedback: timeout has occured, and the result of the `Future`. The requester then get confused and so do I :S

Comment: If you cancel a task, but it runs to completion get() also returns CancellationException, even though it finished.

Comment: You could have your task check its timeout as the first thing it does and throw an exception if it has timed out.  When you use get() you will be able to get a result or this exception.

Comment: This is getting more complicated. I'm actually using the `get(TIMEOUT, timeunit)` in the requester thread and catch the TimeoutException (TE) there. When the TE occurs, if the request is not in progress then I'll cancel it and return with timeout result immediately, but if it's in progress I'll loop again the `get(timeout)` until it finishes.

Comment: If I were to use the CancellationException then I need to cancel it from again another thread and I really don't want to do that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I aware this is an old question, but what about using [Future.isDone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone%28%29) ?

Comment: The `Future.isDone()` only let you know if the task has been completed or not. If it return false it can still be either the task is in progress but not done yet, but not started at all. I want to know whether the task is already in progress or not started yet at all.